# Run XEN on KVM (xen restart unexpectedly)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, xen, proxmox

I 'm Trying to install Xen Above kvm (proxmox ve) , it runs smoothly . but when I try to create and run a vm , xen always restart unexpectedly. What should I do. if anyone has ever tried it ? i hope someone can help me. thanks

Comment: A would try tip #3 from that blog post; http://www.nux.ro/archive/2014/11/Nested_virt___Xenserver_on_KVM.html

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @yagmoth555 . I'm sure VMX flag is already set to on , and I had previously been to enable nested parameters. Initially I used the default processor kvm 64 , when it tries to make a virtual machine on xen , he said HVM is requred , then I tried one by one type of processors available and the results are still the same . until finally I changed into a **host** processor type , but when I tried xen virtual machine always restarts itself . I hope to find a solution soon

Answer (score 0):

Well it should work fine, as I have done it for many users.

You can install Xen on KVM vps but you will be able to create only Xen-PV vps through this Xen host.